# vb excel change shape different sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, shapes

I have two sheets, one called Form where I have the vb code below.
And another sheet called Infographics where I have some shapes.

In the Form sheet I have a cell E7, the value of this cell comes from a formula ( =IF(D7="Yes",1, IF(D7="No",0)) ).
Depended of 1 or 0 it should change the shape (called step1) in the other sheet.
However it doesn't work.
When doing this all in the same sheet it works fine.

Any idea what I am missing here?

In my Form sheet I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("E7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
    If Target.Value = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Infographic").Shapes("Step1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    ElseIf Target.Value = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Infographic").Shapes("Step1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
    Else
        Worksheets("Infographic").Shapes("Step1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGrey
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How far does it get when you debug it?

Comment: No issue on the debugging, I see however what is not working, if I type a 0 or 1 in E7 it is working. But when E7 is automatically get a 0 or 1 through mu filter/formulate it is not working, Any idea how it can see the cell is updated?